# How can I combine two non-sequential git commits into one?

Tags: git

If the following is a list of commits on a branch:

```
A - B - C - D
```

How can I combine commits A and C into (AC)?

```
(AC) - B - D
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First do `git rebase -i aaaaaa^` and then your text editor will show up looking like this:

```
pick aaaaaa
pick bbbbbb
pick cccccc
pick dddddd
```

Change it so that it looks like

```
pick aaaaaa
squash cccccc
pick bbbbbb
pick dddddd
```

and close it and git does the rest.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: And the obligatory warning: don't do this if you've already pushed any of this work.

Comment: Also, to clarify, `A` in the first command is the SHA1 of commit `A` (it may be abbreviated), and `aaaaaa` and friends in the editor are abbreviated SHA1s of the four commits.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase -i A^
```

edit them so that `C` is after `A`.  Change the `pick` to `f` (fixup) and save.